# Link click function of parent object to redirect to href

Tags: jquery, object, scope, this

I'm feeling so dumb asking this question, but I can't figure out a clean way to write this...

Heres the HTML

```
<li>
<a class='link_parent' href='#'>Test</a>
</li>
```

I want the click function of the parent LI to redirect the href of the a with .link_parent...

so...

```
$('a.link_parent').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().click(function() {
    // Need to access $(this).attr('href') of the above object
    // but can't since $(this) is now the <li> object
    // help!
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a.link_parent').each(function() {
    var link = this;
    $(this).parent().click(function() {
        link.attr('href');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li").click(function(){
  $("a.link_parent", this).trigger("click");
});
```

Just a short explanation of scope. `this` is not the only way to get access to items:

```
$("a.link_parent").each(function(i,o){
  // 'o' will always be a reference to this anchor
  $(this).parent().click(function(e){
    // 'e.currentTarget' will be a reference to this parent
    alert(o + " " + e.currentTarget);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the other way round.Dont know the exact JQuery way of writing it.

Add a click event to the "li" element and grab its first child i.e. the "a: element and get its href.